# How to avoid generating zip files in php with folders inside?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zip

I have the following problem: on my website people can download zip files with images inside. Depending on the images, they are in one directory or another. The download is made through an ajax call to a php file that returns this zip file. The problem is that the zip file replicates the folder structure that I have locally, so that inside the zip there are several folders until I reach the files. I would like to know how to put all the files in a single folder, so that when you open the zip you will see the images.

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "download.php",
        data: {
            'imagenes': imagenes,
            'nombreZip': nombreZip
            },
        success: function(data){
            window.location = data;
            $('#fondoDescarga').fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

Where "imagenes" is an array with the files, includingthe root, something like:

0: "contenido/all/MyFolder/Image.tif"
1: "contenido/all/MyFolder/Image2.tif"
2: "contenido/all/MyFolder/Image3.tif"

And this is the php file that generate the zip:

```
<?php  
$error = ""; //error holder  
$post = $_POST;    
if(extension_loaded('zip'))  {
// Checking ZIP extension is available  
    // Checking files are selected  
    $zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library   
    $zip_name = $_POST['nombreZip'].".zip";           // Zip name  
    if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {   
            // Opening zip file to load files  
            $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";  
    }  
    foreach($post['imagenes'] as $file)  {   
            $zip->addFile($file);
    }  
    $zip->close(); 
    echo $zip_name;
} else {  
    $error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";  
}
```

?>

Its quite simple and it works, but it's a bit annoying to force the user to browse so many folders.

Thanks !

Comment: Use the second parameter on `$zip->addFile()` to set name and path for the new file. Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Comment: Thank you very much, now I´m feeling stupid :)